# Join multiple tables for one entity with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, multiple-tables

I was wondering if it was possible to create an entity that fetches data from multiple tables.

I have an entity based on a TableA.

The particularity is that I also need data from TableD, which is linked to TableC, which is linked to TableB finally linked to TableA with TableA id

I am fully aware that I could create an entity on TableB,C,D.
But I don't need ANY data on those tables except on TableD. B and C are just "a path to follow".

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/878537schema.png

I saw the @SecondaryTables annotation that I could use on EntityA but it seems like you can only join with the PK of EntityA.

If you know a solution that will prevent me from creating useless entities, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Create a database view and map one entity to that? I fail to see how entities can be labelled useless when you actually want to fetch data from their respective tables.

Comment: @Gimby I updated my post with a schema to highlight my issue.
I'm using a database I didn't create so I have to do with it

Comment: The view approach suggested by @Gimby is the only approach I can see if you do not want to map B,C,D. You can then map fields of A to this view using the view as a Secondary Table or, have the view as an entity in a one-to-one with A.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I'll go for it

Answer (score -1):

You can link each entity through inheritance strategy InheritanceType.JOINED. Then you can get all values of parent classes in child class.